# Using TensorFlow to predict inital values for curve fitting

Tags: tensorflow, curve-fitting, tf.keras

I have a mass of data, which needs to have curves fitted to based on some complicated mathematical function, and want to use SciPy's curve_fit function to do so.

My problem is, that finding or predicting the initial values for fitting based on some aspects of the data is extremely tedious to do manually, but crucial as fits will be nonsensical if the inital values are not relatively accurate. This is why I am hoping to train a neural network to do this relatively reliably using TensorFlow.

To this end, I tried writing a custom loss function for training, that runs scipy.optimize.curve fit on the training data with the predicted inital parameters, to judge how closely the optimized parameters match with the true parameters used in generating the training data.

However, since you are apparently only allowed to use tensorflows built-in math operations in the custom loss function, I am at a loss at how to actually implement this.

Here is a small example of what I am trying to do, with a linear function:

```
import scipy
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def linear_function(x, m, n):
    return m*x+n


def custom_loss(x):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):

        loss = []
        # determine the loss for each set of data, based on the output of curve_fit
        for i in range(len(x)):
            x_data, y_data = np.split(x[i], 2)
            result_from_prediction, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(linear_function,
                                                              x_data,
                                                              y_data,
                                                              p0=y_pred[i])  # The inital parameters are predicted by the model

            # The loss for each set is then the MSE between the result of the curve fit and the true parameters used in generating the data
            loss.append(np.sum(np.sqrt((y_true - result_from_prediction) ** 2)))

        return sum(loss)
    return loss

# Create some sample input data and labels
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 9]])
y_true = np.array([[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]])

# Define the model architecture
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(x.shape[1],)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])

# Compile the model with the custom loss function
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss(x))

# Train the model ...
model.fit(x=x, y=y_true, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

This just raises

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (loss/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.
```

Since scipy can't handle Tensors.

Suggestions on how to handle this are much appreciated!

Comment: In some cases of functions non-linear regression can be carried out without initial "guessed" values of the parameters thanks to a non conventional method which doesn't requieres iterative calculus. Unfortunately this doesn't works for all kind of functions. If you give a list of the kind of functions that you consider It might be possible to say if they are compatible with this special method.

Comment: @JJacquelin For now, I am attempting to fit sinusoids to non-uniformly sampled data, with little available datapoints for every set of data. Would the method you are suggesting work in this case?

Comment: Fitting equation models made of a combination of sinusidal functions is a difficult case. Nevertheless it is often successful. At least one get rough values of the parameters which can be used as good initial values for classical non-linear regession. If you post an example of data I could easily check with my available application. The general principle of the method is explained in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . Some numerical examples are shown. The application to specific cases sometimes requires a few complementary adaptation.

Comment: For example a very simple case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75222565/sine-curve-fitting-in-python/75246270#75246270